# Turtle Graphics - Resize Shapes To Display

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I am using Python 2.7. I can only use the turtle module to create a game. My **1920 x 1080 display** scales all the images perfectly and the animations play fine, but *(for example)* on a **1280 x 720 display**, the images don't scale properly. I'm using `turtle.shape()` for the images. How do I fix this?

I've added an image

[image]

and a [video](https://youtu.be/cqTCn0GW6lI) to explain the problem further.

As you can see the icons overlap and the image bounces back and fourth instead of going straight on.

This is how I define my screensize:

```
screen_width = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) - ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) / 4

screen_height = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) - ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) / 4
```

- It takes the display size and **minuses itself divided by 4** for the final display of the window.

Comment: Sounds like you're making hardcoded assumptions about the window size somewhere.

Comment: This is how I define the screensize: (Added to post)

Comment: Anyone got anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't fully test this in my environment and without your code.  The idea is to use virtual coordinates so scaling is done at a level where individual graphical elements are handled uniformly:

```
import turtle

VIRTUAL_ASPECT_RATIO = 1.8
VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 2000
VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = VIRTUAL_WIDTH / VIRTUAL_ASPECT_RATIO

screen_width = 3 * ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) / 4
screen_height = 3 * ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) / 4

# attempt to adjust the real window to match the virtual aspect ratio
if screen_width / VIRTUAL_ASPECT_RATIO < screen_height:
    screen_height = screen_width / VIRTUAL_ASPECT_RATIO
elif screen_height * VIRTUAL_ASPECT_RATIO < screen_width:
    screen_width = screen_height * VIRTUAL_ASPECT_RATIO
else:
    pass  # probably need to do something where we adjust both

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(screen_width, screen_height)  # size the real window
screen.setworldcoordinates(-VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2, -VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2, VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2)  # virtual coordinates

yertle = turtle.Turtle()

yertle.circle(100)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Let us know how the above works out for you.

Comment: I used the aspect ratios and they worked fine, apart from the animation on a 1280 x 720 screen didn't fully work. When I used the `.setworldcoordinates` the images overlapped, without it, it worked as intended. Thanks.